# i am not able open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ how to slove?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
Retry to connect

it shown these error?

Comment: This is not a question. Can you please review it?

Comment: Which stack are you using? Is this xamp or LAMP ? It looks like you did not provide the required credentials to MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

These two error messages indicate that phpMyAdmin is not able to communicate with the MySQL server. Most likely, your MySQL server is not running or has stopped for some reason. Check the XAMPP control panel for details and to confirm whether the service is running. You can also view the logs to see why startup was unsuccessful.

Other possible failure explanations include phpMyAdmin connecting to the wrong port or using the wrong password, but since you're using XAMPP those are properly configured by default. Unless you've made more changes that you haven't mentioned, the service/daemon not running is the most likely explanation.